# Updating a value with PaintComponent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I've been making a color matching game, and I've decided to make another window to keep track of how many moves the user has left until reset, as well as a timer that will be used to keep track of a high score eventually.

This is my first experience using `Graphics`, I can't seem to get the value of my counter to update in the window, it stays at it's initial value of 4 moves. I assume the timer will have the same problem of staying at the initial value as-well.

Inside of the Gridworld, the counter updates how it's supposed to. Could someone explain why the counter wouldn't be updating inside of my Score window? I'm sure it's something obvious but I've been starring at this code for the past hour and can't figure it out.

**TileGame Class**

```
import info.gridworld.grid.Grid;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;
import info.gridworld.world.World;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TileGame extends World<TileCritter> {
public TileGame() {
    Color[] colors = { Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GRAY,
            Color.GREEN, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE,
            Color.PINK, Color.RED };
    for (Color color : colors) {
        add(getRandomEmptyLocation(), new TileCritter(color));
        add(getRandomEmptyLocation(), new TileCritter(color));
    }
    setMessage("Click on the first tile to reveal its color. Click on a second to try to find a match. \n"
            + "If you don't find a match within 3 turns, all matches will be reset and the board shuffled.");
    first = true;
}

public boolean locationClicked(Location loc) {
    Grid<TileCritter> gr = getGrid();
    TileCritter t = gr.get(loc);
    if (t != null) {
        t.flip();
        if (first) {
            if (firstTile != null) {
                firstTile.flip();
                secondTile.flip();
            }
            firstTile = t;
            setMessage("Turns until reset: " + (counter - 1));
            first = false;
        } else {
            if (firstTile.getColor().equals(t.getColor())) {
                firstTile = secondTile = null;
                counter = 4;
            } else {
                secondTile = t;
            }
            setMessage("Turns until reset: " + (counter - 1));
            first = true;
            counter--;
            shuffle(gr, t);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void shuffle(Grid<TileCritter> gr, TileCritter t) {
    if (counter == 0) {
        ArrayList<Location> locs = gr.getOccupiedLocations();
        for (Location l : locs) {
            gr.remove(l);

        }
        Color[] colors = { Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY,
                Color.GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.MAGENTA,
                Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED };
        for (Color color : colors) {
            add(getRandomEmptyLocation(), new TileCritter(color));
            add(getRandomEmptyLocation(), new TileCritter(color));
        }
        counter = 4;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Score();
    new TileGame().show();
    Score main = new Score();
    main.display();
}

private TileCritter firstTile;
private TileCritter secondTile;
private boolean first;
public static int counter = 4;

}
```

**Score Class**

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Score extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public Score() {
    setTitle("Score");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void display() {
    add(new CustomComponent());
    pack();        
    setMinimumSize(getSize());
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
}
}

class CustomComponent extends JComponent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedTime = 0L;

@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
    return new Dimension(100, 100);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    int width = 450;
    int height = 150;
    return new Dimension(width, height);
}

public long timer() {
     while (elapsedTime < 2*60*1000) {
            elapsedTime = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
        }
     return elapsedTime;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 16 ));
    g.drawString("Time", 75, 50);
    g.drawString("Moves Remaining", 250, 50);
    String paintCounter = String.valueOf(TileGame.counter);
    g.drawString(paintCounter, 310, 75);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your trying to do it this way, when a couple of `JLabel`s would probably do the job nicely...The problem is, how does the `CustomComponent` know when it should update?

Comment: Ill try it with `JLabel` and let you know the results...

Comment: You'll still have an issue with labels need to be told that they should change their values...which is the core of your problem

Comment: Ok, I have an idea, ill let you know how it goes...